# ASP datagrid not displaying all items

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datagrid

I have recently had to recompile someone's old C#/ASP/.Net website (files indicate it was started over 9 years ago) in order to perform a change on the site. This is a development copy on the same server as the original site.

I cannot get the datagrid to display all of the items on an order confirmation page. I am sure that the correct data is being supplied to the datagrid (as I have printed this out the line before the data gets bound, yet it only displays 2 out of the three items. The code works on the old compilation though!

Here is the c# code: in the .aspx.cs file:

```
SqlDataReader basketReader = User.GetBasket(User.GetUserID(Page.User.Identity.Name));

if (basketReader.Read())
{
    orderDG.DataKeyField = "ItemCode";
    orderDG.DataSource = basketReader;
    orderDG.DataBind();
    basketReader.Close();
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Orders.aspx", false);
}
```

Here is the datagrid code in the .aspx file:

```
<asp:datagrid id="orderDG" runat="server" width="100%" autogeneratecolumns="False" GridLines="none">                                            
    <headerstyle CssClass="dataHeading"></headerstyle>
    <itemstyle CssClass="dataTxt"></itemstyle>
    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#F9F9FF" />
    <columns>
        <asp:boundcolumn datafield="ItemCode" headertext="Item Code"></asp:boundcolumn>
        <asp:boundcolumn datafield="Description" headertext="Description"></asp:boundcolumn>
        <asp:boundcolumn datafield="Quantity" headertext="Quantity"></asp:boundcolumn>
    </columns>
</asp:datagrid>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should call basketReader.Read() before binding.  Try using this instead :

```
SqlDataReader basketReader = User.GetBasket(User.GetUserID(Page.User.Identity.Name));

if (basketReader.HasRows)
{
    orderDG.DataKeyField = "ItemCode";
    orderDG.DataSource = basketReader;
    orderDG.DataBind();
    basketReader.Close();
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Orders.aspx", false);
}
```